# Styling the Typeahead drop down in Bootstrap UI

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on an app that uses AngularJS and Bootstrap. To help, I'm using [Bootstrap UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). In this project, I'm using the typeahead control. I'm trying to make the list that appears below the text box, the same width as the text box itself. No matter what. At this time, it's always changing size. However, I'm not sure how to do this get the suggestion box to go be the same width as the text box. Currently, I'm trying the following:

[**Here is my plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/KUGqkEhjfLJvBQjRaGyr?p=preview)

Currently, I have the following, which isn't working.

```
.dropdown-menu {
  width:75%;
}
```

Can someone help me get the width of the suggestion list to be the same width as the text box?

Thank you!

Comment: can you try to give min-width: 75% !important and check if it works?

Comment: I tried adding `!important`. Unfortunately, that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS3 `calc()` to calculate a width of the `.dropdown-menu` dynamically.

```
.dropdown-menu{
   width: -moz-calc(100% - 28px);
   width: -webkit-calc(100% - 28px);
   width: calc(100% - 28px);
}
```

and remove `white-space: nowrap;` from `.dropdown-menu>li>a`. Hope it will help you!